# Adding a dollar sign to a text field in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Is there a way to add a "$" right before the `<input>` for a Zend_Form element? (using standard ZF stuff would be great, of course).

**EDIT**: For example, if the html generated by Zend_Form for a `cost` element is something like: (very simplified)

```
<label>Cost:</label>
<input type="text" name="cost" />
```

I'd like it to output this:

```
<label>Cost:</label>
$ <input type="text" name="cost" />
```

Comment: please put an example of what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [callback](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.callback) decorator to put whatever html you want in your elements:

For example in your case I could do:

```
    $el1 = $this->createElement('text', 'el1')->setLabel('Cost:');

    // Anonymous function that will generate your custom html (needs PHP 5.3).
    // For older PHP there are other ways of making anonymous functions.
    $myHtml = function($content, $element, array $options) {
                return '$';
            };
    $el1->setDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('Callback', array('callback' => $myHtml, 'placement' => 'PREPEND')),
        'Label'
    ));
```

This should result in the following html code:

```
<label for="el1" class="optional">Cost:</label> 
$
<input type="text" name="el1" id="el1" value="" />
```

Hope this will be helfull or at least point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [AnyMarkup](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62/anymarkup-decorator) decorator, you could do something this:

```
$element->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array('AnyMarkup', array('markup' => '$', 'placement' => 'prepend')),
    // And any other decorators, like Label, Description, Errors, and 
    // other wrapping like td, tr, etc.
));
```

As usual, be sure to register the namespace for the decorator with the form. So, if you use the class as named in the linked snippet `My_Decorator_AnyMarkup` located in the file `My/Decorator/AnyMarkup.php` on the include path, then you'd need something like:

`$form->addElementPrefixPath('My_Decorator_', 'My/Decorator', 'decorator');`

Comment: Good answer, but I'd like it better if it didn't use any extra stuff. Can't this be done using the standard Description decorator?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a description

```
$this->createElement('text', 'cost')
     ->setLabel('Cost:')
     ->setDescription('$');
```

And then configure element's decorators properly.

**Upd:**

Suggested element's decorators:

```
array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array('Description', array('placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::PREPEND, 'tag' => 'em'))
);
```

Note the placement option.

Comment: Doesn't this add the $ sign _after_ the `<input>` element?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I can't get it to work though.. but it's probably something I'm doing elsewhere in the form (I'm kinda new to Zend_Form, need to read some more about decorators..)