# How can I display percentage symbol beside textbox using zend_form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to display a percentage symbol beside a textbox using zend_form. How I can do that?

Comment: Very similar: [Adding a dollar sign to a text field in Zend Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328529/adding-a-dollar-sign-to-a-text-field-in-zend-framework/5329215#5329215)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setLabel() within a class extension of the Zend_Form class.  For example:

```
class Application_Form_Discount extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('discount');

        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');

        $discount= new Zend_Form_Element_Text('discount');
        $discount->setLabel('Discount')
               ->setRequired(true)
               ->addFilter('StripTags')
               ->addFilter('StringTrim')
               ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
                   ->setDescription('%')
                   ->setDecorators(array(
             'ViewHelper',
             array('Description', array('placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::APPEND, 'tag' => 'em'));


        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($id, $discount, $submit));
    }


}
```

You can then render the form directly from the controller action:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Discount();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
        $this->view->form = $form;
```

This would display a text box on the form with a label of "Discount", the Textbox, and then an  tag containing your % symbol.

Comment: I need % symbol after textbox, for example: Discount: textbox %, how can I achieve this, please help...thanx

Comment: Ah, got it.  I updated the code sample to use setDecorators() to put the % in an <em> tag after the textbox.